# "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast" waning in array initialization

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, compiler-warnings

I am now starting to learn C.  I would like to know why I get the warning. I declared a bidimensional char array, but why the character `"d"` is not allowed?

```
char array[3][3] = {{1,"d",3},{3,2,1},{2,1,3}};
```

Comment: `"d"` should be `'d'` a character not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "d" with 'd'

'd' is a character

"d" is a string

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** -- `"d"` is not a character, it's a *string*. `'d'` is a character.

---

To elaborate, we use single quotes `''` to denote a `char`. It represents the *value* of that `char`. That value is `int` type.

OTOH, The double quotes `" "` are used to denote a string. It retruns the base address of the *string*. That is a pointer.

In your code, you have used `"d"`, which returns a pointer to a *string literal*, to initialize a `char` variable, which expects an value of type `int`. Hence the warning.